# Excel VBA - Add rows as described in a table

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to replicate [this view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSKKh.png) where new rows in the bottom table are created based on the values in Column'A' of the top table.

Here is my code:

```
Sub testProc()
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Dim r, count As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim temp As Integer
'Dim lngLastRow As Long

Set r = Range("A:L")
Set count = Range("A:A")
LastRow = Range("F" & 9).End(xlUp).Row
'LastRow = Cells(Rows.count, MyRange.Column).End(xlUp).Row
For n = LastRow To 1 Step -1
    temp = Range("A" & n)
    If (temp > 0) Then
        Rows(n + 1 & ":" & n + temp).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Range("H" & (ActiveCell.Row) - 2).Copy Range("E" & (ActiveCell.Row) - 1)
        Range("G" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select

        'ActiveCell.Offset(RowOffset:=1, ColumnOffset:=-6).Activate
        'Cells(ActiveRow, 8).Value.Cut
        'Cells.Offset(2 - 6).Value.Paste

        'Range("G" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select
        'ActiveCell.Offset(0 - Selection.Column + 1).Range("A1:AG1").Select
        'Value = Range(G, H)
        'ActiveCell.Offset(1, -6).Paste
        'ActiveCell.Offset(1, -6).Paste
        'ActiveCell.Offset(RowOffset:=1, ColumnOffset:=-6).Paste

        'Range.Offset(1, -6).Paste
        'Value = Range("G" & (ActiveCell.Row), "H" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value

        'ActiveCell.Offset(2, -6).Range


        'ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=3, columnOffset:=3).Activate

    End If
Next n
End Sub
```

I do not know what I am doing and Excel is crashing with and without messages

Comment: Welcome to StackOverlow.  Please take a look at this guide for asking a good Question: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Comment: To be specific, your Question is really difficult to understand, and we can't see the code that you're using either.

Comment: Hi Graham, thank you for your  reply. Have you seen the linked image? I tried to make it as clear as I could - please see text description below:

I need to insert rows into a range A1:J151 according to values in column'A' (2 rows of data provided as example)
then move the dispersed date values in columns(F:J) into a single pair of Start/End columns(B8:C8. 
Where I have 2 pairs of dates I insert 2 rows, where I have 3 pairs of dates (*I am treating the single date in J3 as a repeated pair as in B15:C15) . I then need to loop it. I can add rows but not move data without stopping the loop.

Comment: Yes, I have seen the image and it's still not clear to me (I have 25+ years experience as an Excel power user with nearly as much VBA experience).  Please don't add the description to the comments - you need to edit your question.

Comment: Thank you Graham. I hope this is right now?

Comment: Much better.  Now you need to post the messages that you're getting from Excel and it will be a good question.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution to this would be to use two separate worksheets, but you can work around this pretty easily with some math or a cell with a reserved word.  You also want to use as few reference variables as possible and let Excel tell you what the ranges are defined as by using contiguous ranges.

I'm not going to write the whole function for you, but give you the building blocks that will let you piece it together and hopefully you'll learn more as you do it.

Here's how to set up the object variables that you'll reference throughout the code:

```
Dim sourceSheet as Worksheet
Dim targetSheet as Worksheet

' replace with the names of sheets you want to use
sourceSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
targetSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")
```

Now, for looping through the source table.  If you know that the first row in the Sheet is always the Title row and your instructions start in row 2 then you can use this to loop through every instruction:

```
Dim sourceRowIndex = 2

While Not IsEmpty(sourceSheet.cells(sourceRowIndex, 1))

  ' ** do stuff here

  ' increment row index
  sourceRowIndex = sourceRowIndex + 1

Wend
```

You could also use a For Each loop or a For Next or a Do While, take your pick once you understand the logic used.

Note that "Cells" takes two numbers - the row number then the column number.  This is very handy when you're looping through a series of rows and columns and don't want to have to deal with addresses like A1 or C5.

This will loop through everything in the top table, but now you need to add an inner loop that will actually process the instructions.  Add all of the code below after the While and before the Wend.

Finally, you need to add the rows to the Target.  The trick here is to use the CurrentRegion property to figure out where the last row in the range is, then just add one to get the next blank row.

```
Dim targetFirstEmptyRow

' Look up the Current Range of cell A1 on target worksheet
targetFirstEmptyRow = targetSheet.cells(1,1).CurrentRegion.Rows + 1
```

Then to assign values don't use copy and paste, just assign the values directly.  This will write the first row you have defined:

```
targetSheet.cells(targetFirstEmptyRow, 1).value = sourceSheet.cells(sourceRowIndex, 1).value
targetSheet.cells(targetFirstEmptyRow, 4).value = sourceSheet.cells(sourceRowIndex, 4).value
targetSheet.cells(targetFirstEmptyRow, 5).value = sourceSheet.cells(sourceRowIndex, 5).value
```

Then after you write out those three values you can get the next empty row by using this again (note that your sourceRowIndex hasn't changed):

```
targetFirstEmptyRow = targetSheet.cells(1,1).CurrentRange.Rows + 1
```

Using the cells(row, column) logic it's pretty easy to write the second row as well:

```
targetSheet.cells(targetFirstEmptyRow, 2).value = sourceSheet.cells(sourceRowIndex, 6).value
targetSheet.cells(targetFirstEmptyRow, 3).value = sourceSheet.cells(sourceRowIndex, 7).value
targetSheet.cells(targetFirstEmptyRow, 6).value = "Dev"
```

Adding the third row (when it's required) is nearly exactly the same as the second.  However, you want to check to see if the third row is necessary:

```
If sourceWorksheet.cells(sourceRowIndex, 1) = 3 Then
  ' insert your third row here
End If
```

Here's the entire function in pseudo-code so you can piece it all together:

```
Set up worksheet variables
While loop through every Source row
  Find next empty row in Target
  Copy Row 1
  Find next empty row in Target
  Copy Row 2
  If 3 rows
    Find next empty row in Target
    Copy Row 3
  Increment Source Row Index
Wend
```

Finally, if you don't want to see the screen flashing (and you want to speed the code execution up a little) look into Application.Screenupdating to turn off screen redraw as this does its work.  Just remember to turn it on again once you've finished processing everything.