# VBA Do While Loop Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel, loops, paste

I am trying to create a macro that when a button named "Run Formula" is clicked, it copies a specific block of cells starting from I12, then moves down 28 rows and pastes the formulas from the block of cells in I40. It then loops to do this 150 times. 
Note: I did make this work by recording a Macro and copy and pasting 150 times but I'd like to edit the code to be simpler.
I have never used VBA before but this is what I have so far:

```
    Sub Button6_Click()
    Button6_Click Macro
    Range("I12:AG22").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    Do While i < 150
    Row 40 + i * 28
    i = i + 1
    Loop
    End Sub
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The code you've posted makes no effort to do what you've described. The loop does nothing but increment a variable (`Row`); it makes no effort to do anything with that variable after it's incremented. In order for it to accomplish anything, it has to affect the cells somehow. There's not even an effort to do anything with the cells you've copied at all.

Comment: please describe, in detail, end result that you wish to accomplish

Comment: Take a look at this answer I typed up this morning: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45558891/excel-vba-add-rows-as-described-in-a-table?noredirect=1#comment78079633_45558891  Does that work for you?

Comment: are you copying a block of cells ( I12:AG22 by 150 rows) down to I40?  you can easily record a macro that does that.  why would you even do that one row at a time?

Comment: one thing that puzzles me, you said **specific** block of cells. what do you mean when you say "specific"? do you mean cells with values? cells with formulas?

Comment: @jsotola  He says "a specific block of cells" and in his code snippet he has `Range("I12:AG22")` so I think that's what he means by "specific block"  But he only wants to paste the formulas...

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you trying to paste the value of I12:AG22 into every 28th cell down, down to row 4200? Or are you trying to copy the formula, move down 28 cells, then paste the 'intelligent formula' there (e.g. I40:AG40), and so on down to row 4200?

Answer (score 1):

use a for loop it will save some typing.

Also avoid the use of `.Select` or `.Activate`

Also get into the habit of always assigning the parent sheet to any Range or Cells object.

```
Sub Button6_Click()
'Button6_Click Macro

Dim i As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change to the name of the sheet
    .Range("I12:AG22").Copy
    For i = 0 to 149
        .Cells(40 + i * 28,"I").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```